# BootstrapVue's b-paginate component renders but doesn't function

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

Please excuse my ignorance as a new web developer, but I can't seem to get the `<b-paginate>` component to work in my single file Django and Vue 2 app.  I access Bootstrap Vue via CDN.

This is my component, which is placed directly above my main Vue app:

```javascript
let paginationComponent = Vue.component('pagination-component', {
    name: 'paginationComponent',
    props:['pantryItems'],
    template:`<div class="overflow-auto"><b-pagination
      v-model="currentPage"
      :total-rows="rows"
      :per-page="perPage"
      first-text="First"
      prev-text="Prev"
      next-text="Next"
      last-text="Last"
      class="mt-4"
    ></b-pagination></div>`,
    
    data: function() {
      return {
        rows: this.pantryItems.length,
        perPage: 10,
        currentPage: 1,
      }

    },
    computed: {
        rows: function() {
            return this.pantryItems.length
        }
    }
})
```

and this is my Vue root app:

```javascript
let mypantryapp = new Vue ({
    el: "#app",
    delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
    components: {'pagination-component': paginationComponent},
    data: {
        pantryItems: [],
        name: '',
        users: [],
        itemName: '', 
        createdDate: '',
        expirationDate: '',
        csrf_token: '',
        itemErrors: {currentUser: false},
        currentUser: {id: false},
        owner: '',
        itemImgs: [],
        tags: [],
        by_category: false,
        grocery_view: false,
```

...followed by a bunch of unrelated methods for my pantry inventory app.

This is how I call it in my HTML:

```html
<b-pagination :pantry-items='pantryItems' ></b-pagination>
```

The component renders on the page with just the number 1 in the middle of the pagination button group and all other buttons greyed out.

Answer (score 0):

The only mistake you've made here is confusing `b-pagination` for your own `pagination-component` child component.

You're invoking `b-pagination` perfectly in your `template` option, you just need to add the child component itself into your HTML to actually use it. The `template` parameter will replace the HTML of your child component in the DOM.

Simply change:

```html
<b-pagination :pantry-items='pantryItems'></b-pagination>
```

to:

```html
<pagination-component :pantry-items='pantryItems'></pagination-component>
```

And it should work correctly! Example below:

```js
let paginationComponent = Vue.component('pagination-component', {
  name: 'paginationComponent',
  props: ['pantryItems'],
  template: `<div class="overflow-auto"><b-pagination
      v-model="currentPage"
      :total-rows="rows"
      :per-page="perPage"
      first-text="First"
      prev-text="Prev"
      next-text="Next"
      last-text="Last"
      class="mt-4"
    ></b-pagination></div>`,

  data: function() {
    return {
      //rows: this.pantryItems.length, *** See note below
      perPage: 1, //Lower perPage for example sake
      currentPage: 1,
    }

  },
  computed: {
    rows: function() {
      return this.pantryItems.length
    }
  }
});

let mypantryapp = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
  components: {
    'pagination-component': paginationComponent
  },
  data: {
    pantryItems: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], //Dummy items for example sake
  }
});
```

```html
<!-- Set up Vue and Bootstrap-Vue for snippet -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap@4/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" /><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" /><script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script><script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <pagination-component :pantry-items='pantryItems'></pagination-component>
</div>
```

As one final note, you need only declare `rows` once. In this case, you should remove it from data, because it will change if your total items changes. Your `computed` `rows` will reflect the change, the `rows` var in `data` will not (since it will be set once at startup and then never again).